# Automating the password protection of XML files using PHP, XSLT, or other languages

Tags: php, xml, xslt, password-protection, password-encryption

I'm attempting to automate the password protection of Microsoft Word documents using PHP or XSLT. I start with close to 100 XMLs that I pull from a database. I then use one XSL file to style them and the resulting XMLs are posted on a website. Finally, I utilize PHP to automatically update the files every time there is a change to the database. The files are downloaded by many people with the intended use in Microsoft Word but, given the sensitivity of some of the information in the files, I need to password protect them.

Usually, to password protect a Microsoft Word Document one would simply go to File >> Protect Document >> Encrypt with Password. However, given that the files themselves are constantly being updated, I need this process to be automated. How can I go about doing so?

I know the question title asks how to do so with PHP or XSLT, but I only list those two options because I am already using them in the process. I am definitely open to using any other languages that can automate the password protecting of these XMLs

Answer (score 0):

Although not a complete solution and also not in either php or XSLT I would have a look at [Office open SDK and documentprotection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.documentprotection.aspx). It uses c# but you should be able to write a small wrapper that you can use in your process.